# event emitter emit in sequence or in parallel, and behaviour when they are async

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following code:

```
import events from 'events';

const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on('flush', (arg)=>{
    let i=0;
    while(i<=100000){
        console.log(i, arg);

        i++;
    }
})

setTimeout(()=>{
    eventEmitter.emit('flush', `Fourth event`);
}, 5000);

setTimeout(()=>{
    eventEmitter.emit('flush', `Third event`);
}, 4000);

setTimeout(()=>{
    eventEmitter.emit('flush', `First event`);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(()=>{
    eventEmitter.emit('flush', `Second event`);
}, 3000);
```

**Output1:**

```
1 First event
2 First event
3 First event
.
.
.
1 Second event
2 Second event
3 Second event
.
.
.
1 Third event
2 Third event
3 Third event
.
.
.
1 Fourth event
2 Fourth event
3 Fourth event
```

What I wanted to know was, does the event that is emitted get completed first then only the second event get emitted? Or can I expect something like this:

**Output2:**

```
1 First event
1 Second event
2 Third event
3 Fourth event
3 Third event
.
.
.
```

What if I wrote the `emitter.on` function like this:

```
eventEmitter.on('flush', (arg)=>{
    const mFunc = async ()=>{
    let i=0;
    while(i<=100000){
        console.log(i, arg);
        i++;
        }
    }
    mFunc();
})
```

I was expecting output like `Output2`, but, instead I got something similar to `Output1`. Could someone please explain me this behaviour?

Also, consider this case:

```
eventEmitter.on('flush', (arg)=>{
    const mFunc = async ()=>{
    let i=0;
    while(i<=100000){
        console.log(i, arg);
        i++;
        await updateValueInDatabase(i);
        }
    }
    mFunc();
})
```

Now, what would be the behaviour of the function?

Comment: Emitting an event from an EventEmitter is 100% synchronous code.  It does not go through the event loop.  So, one you call `.emit()`, those event handlers will run until they are done before any other system events (e.g. your timers) can run.

Comment: @jfriend00 , can you explain the behaviour when I use async above? Why don't they give me jumbled output but instead give me a sequential output? Do they wait for the promise or  something before executing the next one on the list?

Comment: Calling an `async` function is NO different from the calling point of view at all than calling a non-async function.  It doesn't change anything.  Now, inside an `async` function, you could use `await` and that would cause it to suspend execution and immediately return a promise, but without `await`, making a function `async` just makes it return a promise, but doesn't change anything else.  So, call the `async` version of `mFunc()` is exactly the same as if it wasn't `async` (except it returns a promise which you don't use).  Doesn't changing sequencing of events at all.

Comment: Since you apparently thought it would change things, I'd really suggest reading a bunch more about what an `async` function is because your perception of what it does is apparently different than what it actually does.  All `async` functions return a promise and catch internal exceptions which they turn into a rejected promise.  If you don't use `await`, they just run synchronously like everything else and then return a promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 , but, calling an async function returns immediately, which a `non-async` function doesn't, right? That way wouldn't another `emit` be allowed to execute immediately?

Comment: NO.  Calling an async function returns ONLY when you hit an `await` or when the function finishes executing and hits a `return` or the implicit `return` at the end of the function.  If there's no `await`, it just runs like a normal function and then returns a promise (which you aren't doing anything with).  As I said above, you really need to read more about what `async` functions actually are.  Your current understanding is apparently incorrect.

Comment: @jfriend00 , I edited my code above, now, in such a case, can I expect something like output2 i.e. a jumbled output?

Comment: It creates a mess here when you MODIFY existing code to change the question being asked as all previous discussion now makes no sense for those who come later to read this.  You CAN add a new case that you want to add to your question if that is needed to understand the original question.  Can you please fix that in your question?  That `await` will probably change things.

Comment: @jfriend00 , I edited it. Do you mean the await can jumble things up?

Comment: Well, queued promises waiting to notify get to run before `setTimeout()` callbacks so "it's complicated".  It also depends upon what `updateValueInDatabase(i)` does and what it returns and how long it takes to resolve its promise if that's what it returns and whether it has any actual asynchronous code in it before it resolves a promise it returns.

Comment: @jfriend00 , so you mean emitter.emit(....) doesn't wait for the promise to get resolved (or rejected) for running the next function?

Comment: Let's move our commentary to my answer below as I've added more explanation there.  Please read that, then comment on what you don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coalescing my comments into an answer and adding more commentary and explanation...

Emitting an event from an `EventEmitter` is 100% synchronous code. It does not go through the event loop. So, once you call `.emit()`, those event handlers will run until they are done before any other system events (e.g. your timers) can run.

Calling an `async` function is NO different from the calling point of view at all than calling a non-async function. It doesn't change anything. Now, inside an `async` function, you could use `await` and that would cause it to suspend execution and immediately return a promise, but without `await`, making a function async just makes it return a promise, but doesn't change anything else. So, calling the `async` version of mFunc() is exactly the same as if it wasn't `async` (except it returns a promise which you don't use). Doesn't changing sequencing of events at all.

Since you apparently thought it would change things, I'd really suggest reading a bunch more about what an `async` function is because your perception of what it does is apparently different than what it actually does. All `async` functions return a promise and catch internal exceptions which they turn into a rejected promise. If you don't use `await`, they just run synchronously like everything else and then return a promise.

Calling an `async` function returns ONLY when you hit an `await` or when the function finishes executing and hits a `return` or the implicit `return` at the end of the function. If there's no `await`, it just runs like a normal function and then returns a promise (which you aren't doing anything with). As I said above, you really need to read more about what `async` functions actually are. Your current understanding is apparently incorrect.

Here are some summary characteristics of an `async` function:

1. They always return a promise.
2. That promise is resolved with whatever value the function eventually returns with a `return` statement or resolved with `undefined` if no `return` statement.
3. They **run synchronously** until they either hit a `return` statement or an `await`.
4. At the point they hit an `await`, they immediately return a promise and further execution of the function is suspended until the promise that `await` is on is resolved.
5. When they suspend and return a promise, the caller receives that promise and keeps executing. The caller is not suspended unless the caller also does an `await` on that promise.
6. They also catch any synchronous exceptions or other exceptions that aren't themselves in an asynchronous callback and turn those exceptions into a rejected promise so the promise that the `async` function returns will be rejected with the exception as the reason.
7. So, if there is no `await` in an `async` function, they just run synchronously and return a promise.

In your last version of code, if you end up making your event emitter handler actually be asynchronous and actually `await` long enough for other things to get some cycles, then you can create some competition between timers and promises waiting to notify their listeners.  The promises waiting to notify their listeners will get to run before the timers.  That makes your situation of mixing those two types very complicated and very dependent upon timings.  A non-ending sequence of promises waiting to notify their listeners can make timers wait until there are no more promises waiting to notify.  But, if there's a moment with no promises waiting to notify, then your next timer will fire and will kick off it's own set of promise-driven operations and then all the promise-driven operations will likely interleave.

Also, `emitter.emit()` is not promise-aware.  It doesn't pay any attention to the return value from the callbacks that are listening for the emit.  So, it doesn't make any difference at all to `emitter.emit()` whether the listeners are `async` or not.  As soon as they return (whether they returned a promise or not), it just goes right on to whatever it was going to do next.  Promises only influence code flow if the recipient uses them with `await` or `.then()` and `.catch()`.  In this case, the recipient does nothing with the return value so `emitter.emit()` just goes right onto its next order of business and executes that.

> okay, so, if I have a bunch of async function arrays [async1, async2, async3, ....], and they all have await statements internally, what would be the best way to execute them in sequential order? i.e. one after other in order of their index?

Well, if you had an array of async functions that properly resolve their promise when they are actually done with their work, you can execute them sequentially by just looping through the array with an `await`.

```
async function someFunc() {
    const jobs = [asyncFn1, asyncFn2, asyncFn3];
    for (let job of jobs) {
         let result = await job(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, so, if I have a bunch of async function arrays [async1, async2, async3, ....], and they all have await statements internally, what would be the best way to execute them in sequential order? i.e. one after other in order of their index?

Comment: @BumbleBee - See what I've added to the end of my answer.  But, we are kind of getting to the point where if you want to keep adding more questions, you should probably write a new question.

Comment: Is there an event emitter library that is promise-aware? So that way `emit` when called guarantees resolution of all asynchronous event handlers?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai - Not that I know of.  Promises are not a good match for events that can occur more than once because a promise can only be resolved once, but events can fire multiple times.  Plus, I'm not really sure what you mean by "guarantees resolution of all asynchronous event handlers".   Perhaps you should write your own question and describe the problem you want help with.

Comment: He meant to remain execution orders, await promise in async callback would change the emit order.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, the `EvenEmitter` hold an array of listeners for each event type. When you emit an event type, the `EvenEmitter` just goes through it's array of listeners and execute it. Therefore, the listeners are executed in the order it was added by `addListener` or `on` method.

To answer your questions there are two parts: a) it executes in the order you added the listener and b) it depends if the listeners are async or not. If your listeners are synchronous, then you can expect that behavior. If your listeners are async, you can't expect that. Even if your execute your async synchronously, they will not necessarily resolve at the same time because it's the nature of being async.

Comment: meaning, I'm just being lucky they're giving me result in sequence?

Comment: Output1 is expected. Each of your listeners are going through a for loop. Hence it will execute multiple console log for each event. Your listeners are not truly async. There's no async logic in your listeners. They are just synchronous for loops.

Comment: but, shouldn't the 4 functions be running somewhat parallely?

Comment: Async does not mean functions run in parallel. All functions are run by the event loop. The event loop is synchronous. So if your function (regardless if its async or not) is holding up the event loop, it will block the functions in the event loop queue. Read up on the javascript event loop. Async does not mean parallel. Your for loops are going through 1 million loops, it will block the other async functions from executing.